# Multiple expressions in single statement

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I am trying to understand two situations in C.

Situation - 1:

```
int main() {
    int x = -5, y = 8, z = 2;
    z = y - (y = x);
    printf("%d", z);

    return 0;
}
```

It prints 0.

Situation - 2:

```
int main() {
    int x = -5, y = 8, z = 2;
    x = x + y - (y = x);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

It prints 8.

Why in situation - 1, after (y = x) value inside y is update to -5 and then used in the outer expression while in situation - 2, even after (y = x) value of outside expression's y is still 8?

Comment: Protip re. compound expressions - just don't:)

Comment: Don't do things like this, the authors of the C Programming Language explicitly warn against doing this kind of thing in their book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Order of evaluation of operands in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) is unspecified. As such, expressions like `z = y - (y = x)` invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If I compile your first example, gcc actually warns me about this.

```
% gcc test.c
test.c:5:16: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'y' [-Wunsequenced]
    z = y - (y = x);
        ~      ^
1 warning generated.
```

And the output when *I* run that program is *13*.

Comment: So, will it give different values in different compilers?

Comment: Or even between compilations of the same source with the same compiler. The standard didn't specify the behaviour, so no behavior should be counted upon.

Comment: The key is to never try to anticipate what undefined behavior will be, because _you can't._ Instead seek to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: @RajIshu "implementation-defined behavior" = different behavior on different compilers but deterministic and documented behavior. "undefined behavior" = anything can happen including crashes etc and the behavior is non-deterministic, non-documented, no guarantees of anything. This here is undefined behavior.